# How can I get a list of authorized Endpoints for the current user (Java / Spring-Boot)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, endpoint

I would like to show the user a list of the actions he is allowed to do. For that, I would like to collect a list of all the available Endpoints, to create this List automatically, since it might change depending on the set Authorities, further Endpoints created, etc. A hardcoded list seems a bit wrong for that scenario.

So far I have already tried displaying it with an EndpointListener, via the Spring-Actuator, and via Swagger (which I only tried for this method, I am not further familiar with it).
All of them sadly only seems to List ALL the endpoints, but not exclude those the current user is not authorized for. I also could not find Information in their output that might help in filtering them.

Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK there is no out of the box way, you have to implement it. But there is no easy way, because it depends on the access rules for each endpoint. For example: if the access rule is some complex Spring Expression Language you have to evaluate it.

Comment: The full list should be enough, because the user knows its role.

Comment: The access rule is per @Secured Annotation, I should have included that in the Post.
How could I evaluate if the user has access to a given endpoint? Then I could load the full List and after that evaluate each one if it is accessible for the current user.